# React-Native: Adding a Button on press of a Button

Tags: react-native

A simple question I can't wrap my head around is this:
Let's say I have a button, if I press that button, I want another button to appear. Imagine that buttoncreation as something that loops, so I can't have a predefined list of buttons I just show or hide.

React can create with *react.createElement()*, but I don't seem to get the correct usage of createElement.

Can I steer around having to create Elements through react? (Kind of feels like against the nature of react to actually create new html into something)

> Easier said: I'm currently developing an app that calculates a common route between multiple departures and destinations, I want to give the user the ability to enter as many departures and destinations as he'd like, since the backend algorithm can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
state = {
  buttons: []
}

createButton() {
  let { buttons } = this.state

  const button = (
    <Button 
      onPress={this.createButton.bind(this)} 
    />
  )

  buttons.push(button)

  this.setState({
    buttons
  })
}

renderItem({ item }) {
  return (
    <View>
      {item}
    </View>
  )
}

render() {
  return() {
    <FlatList 
      data={this.state.buttons}
      renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem()}
    />
  }
}
```